# Meteor HTML parser give me challenge

Tags: html, meteor

In my Meteor app, I'm trying to list all the user with a completed profile on a single page. For that, I need them to be as follow :

```
<div class="container">
{{#each talker}}
  {{#if profile.completed}}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span5 talker-card well">
      <span><b>{{profile.username}}</b>, {{profile.location}}</span><br>
      <b>{{profile.languages.native}}</b>
      <p>
        {{profile.bio}}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span5 talker-card well">
      <span><b>{{profile.username}}</b>, {{profile.location}}</span><br>
      <b>{{profile.languages.native}}</b>
      <p>
        {{profile.bio}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Two by two, They must be in a same row sized with a span10, split in two span5.

The problem is that I must define a behavior for the three different cases :

- There is another profile after this one, in the same row
- There is another profile after this one, in the next row
- There is no more profile after this one, and as there is an odd number of profile, I'm the only one in this row

Then, as I'd have done in PHP, the solution would be to check a boolean isOdd, which change to !isOdd at each iteration, allowing me to do something like this :

```
<div class="container">
  {{#each talker}}
    {{#if profile.completed}}
      {{#if isOdd}}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span5 talker-card well">
          <span><b>{{profile.username}}</b>, {{profile.location}}</span><br>
          <b>{{profile.languages.native}}</b>
          <p>
            {{profile.bio}}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="span5 talker-card well">
          <span><b>{{profile.username}}</b>, {{profile.location}}</span><br>
          <b>{{profile.languages.native}}</b>
          <p>
            {{profile.bio}}
          </p>
        </div>
      {{else}}
        <div class="span5 talker-card well">
          <span><b>{{profile.username}}</b>, {{profile.location}}</span><br>
          <b>{{profile.languages.native}}</b>
          <p>
            {{profile.bio}}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="span5 talker-card well">
          <span><b>{{profile.username}}</b>, {{profile.location}}</span><br>
          <b>{{profile.languages.native}}</b>
          <p>
            {{profile.bio}}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

But I can't do such a simple thing as Meteor consider it to be an error to do not close a div in the condition / scope it has been opened ! That's the stupid point with Meteor, unless all its advantages over PHP : it's that strict that it become really hard to handle some simple cases like this.

Can some one give me some tips here ?

Thanks you

Comment: Maybe you could use a more css approach to that problem? Like setting a `float: left` to each of your `.talker-card` elements, and just dump them one-by-one in a div without setting rows every two profile? Here it is not clear how you put two different profiles on a same row, because you seem to print twice the same profile on each row, given the location of your `each` statement...

Comment: I could try something like this. The use of row is to allow to automatically line all the profile on a signle column on mobile devices and small screens

Comment: Did you mean to only have one talker-card div within the {{if}} and one in the {{else}}?  (your code shows two in each, which doesn't make sense).

Comment: The first snippet is only to show something close to what should be visible in the rendered source code.

For the second one, In the {{if isOdd}}, i open a div "row", and i close it in the else. The goal is to determine if i'm placing the card on the right or on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox or alternative jquery methods if you are targeting legacy browsers. Don't try to layout page in application logic. It is a bad idea.